# ¿Habría que datar las referencias a recursos de internet?

Tags: discusión, respuestas, formulado-de-preguntas

En las preguntas (y en las respuestas) con frecuencia se incluyen enlaces a páginas web y se requiere que se cite el texto pertinente.  Pero si con el tiempo el contenido de la página enlazada *cambia* podemos encontrarnos con que el contenido originalmente referenciado ya no existe o es radicalmente diferente, creándose una situación extraña.

¿Sería conveniente, además del enlace y el texto, recoger cuándo se ha realizado? Por ejemplo: "Consultado el día X del mes Y del año Z".

Comment: Relacionado: [Automatically have links archived in the Wayback Machine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331125/295232)

Answer (score 1):

Añadir la fecha de acceso a los enlaces hace el contenido del post más claro, y por tanto es una mejora. Sin embargo, ya requerimos que se copie la parte relevante del enlace, y la información de la fecha se puede ver en el historial de revisiones del post. Por tanto, creo que no es esencial que la fecha de acceso esté incluida en el post. Quien lee un post de hace seis años puede esperar que parte de la información no sea actual. Además, en muchos casos, a diferencia de los sitios de programación, a nosotros nos interesa también la historia de la lengua y no solo el uso actual. La desaparición de una entrada del diccionario no invalida la pregunta/respuesta, sino que normalmente solo requiere editarla cambiando verbos como "se usa" por "se usaba".

Cuando digo que "no es esencial que la fecha esté incluida" me refiero a que, aunque datar los enlaces mejore las publicaciones, no lo impondría como una regla del sitio, ni creo que merezca la pena hacer el esfuerzo de añadir la fecha a todos los enlaces que ya están en el sitio.

Esto es solo mi opinión, claro. Otras opiniones son bienvenidas y si hay un claro consenso haremos los cambios pertinentes.

Comment: (+1) One of the reasons for giving a link is to give credit to the source and that is still relevant even if the source changes.